# How to sculpt and move that figure around

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

I am kind of new to blender and am just getting use to making things that remain in one position. This question might not make sense but I was wondering if there was anyway, once you've finished modeling say a human body could you put it in a different position, (say in a bath tub with legs up on tub) without sculpting a different thing. Like could I grab parts of my first model whos just standing straight and put them in different positions without messing up the whole mesh? Every time I try and move a body part the whole thing gets messed up. I hope that makes sense... thanks!!!

Comment: This is done by constructing an *armature* of bones and *rigging* the model to the armature, then you move the bones around to move the model.  (I'll let somebody with more experience in the process give a full answer.)

Answer (score 2):

In *Sculpt Mode* there's a relatively recent addition called the *[Pose Brush](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools/pose.html#pose)*.  It attempts to move parts of your model as though you had rigged it with a skeleton.

Comment: I don't have the pose brush, do I have to download a new version of blender? or can I just add it from the settings in the version I have now??

Comment: @Clowncar416 It was added in 2.83 it looks like - https://youtu.be/OrhfjhdlRUc

Comment: I don't think you have to do a face set setup to use the pose brush I was just trying to find what version it was added in

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your help!! :)